# Can i make repositories in a NAS in GitHub for Windows?

Tags: git, networking, github

I am using GitHub for Windows. The problem is i can't access a network folder the program alerts:

> UNC paths are not supported

How can i avoid this issue. I want to get a Network Associated Storage (NAS) to work localy and not on a server.

Any solutions or workaround? Or should i use any other software!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a network drive.  Instructions from Microsoft are [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-shortcut-to-map-a-network-drive).  Once you do this, the location will be treated (for pathing purposes) like any other local drive.  Note that this will only connect and work properly if both are on and connected to that network, so for example, if you have a laptop away from home, it won't work.

You might also consider using a cloud based service like [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) to host your repository.  This one in particular allows for free private repositories (with some limitations.